# awk cmd to find n! not working

Tags: awk

I'm not sure why the following awk cmd isn't working:

```
seq 10 | awk 'BEGIN {print "---Numbers---"} {total*=$1} 1; END {print "---Total-----\n" total} '
```

the result is:

```
---Numbers---
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
---Total-----
0
```

But it should be:

```
---Numbers---
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
---Total-----
3,628,800
```

I think it has something to do with total starting off as 0 but I tried adding:

```
{total=1}
```

right before the

```
{total*=$1}
```

and it didn't work

Comment: Initialization of `total` needs to go in the `BEGIN` block ...

Comment: haha no way I missed that, thanks!

Comment: `total` can also be initialized with the `-v` option: `awk -v total=1 { ...`

Comment: oh wow I didn't think of that, thanks!